how to pull all data after a specific order?
I am looking for a way to build a graphQL query to pull order data after a specific order id.
I am using REST today and achieve this by running database query to pull the last loaded order. I then make a call to Shopify and specify:&since_id=<last_loaded_order>.
I've looked into examples on Shopify and cannot find the way to do the same thing in graphQL.
Could someone share a link or a snippet of how to do it?

You can filter orders by id
Example:
query($query: String) {
    orders(first: 250, query: "id:>=5834352591016", sortKey: PROCESSED_AT) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                name
                processedAt
            }
        }
    }
}


Note: id is Shopify order id.

Sorry for a long delay. I owe you a correct answer mark. I was running tests and can confirm that your solution works. Btw, I called Shopify support and asked the same question. They had no clue and said it's not possible. Thank you.

Glad to hear it worked for you.
